# DatabaseManager_Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract method clearAllTables() in RoomDatabase

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I have built this code, it showed build error:

> DatabaseManager_Impl is not abstract and does not override abstract
>   method clearAllTables() in RoomDatabase.

build.gradle:

```
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.1.0-beta3'
```

Database implementation as per Room guidance:

```
@Database(entities = {Task.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class DatabaseManager extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String DATABASE =
                         Iterables.getLast(Splitter.on(".").trimResults().split(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)).concat("-db");
    private static volatile DatabaseManager instance;

    public abstract TaskDao taskDao();

    synchronized public static DatabaseManager onInstance(Context context)     {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = newInstance(context, false);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static DatabaseManager newInstance(Context context, boolean memoryOnly) {
        RoomDatabase.Builder<DatabaseManager> builder;

        if (memoryOnly) {
            builder = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DatabaseManager.class);
        } else {
            builder = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), DatabaseManager.class, DATABASE);
        }

        return builder.fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Any fix for this problem?

Comment: Not yet @KeivanEsbati

Comment: Any update for this?

Comment: After changing android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.1.0-beta3 to android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.0.0, the problem has been solved. @iflorit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for me was to change all of room libraries versions to `1.0.0`

Also make sure to use `kapt` instead of `annotationProccessor`!

Comment: Have you tried to change `android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.1.0-beta3` to  `android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.0.0` @Roman ?

Comment: Thanks  a lot @szymon-wysocki, this helps me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue and realized that

```
//room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:${arch_version}"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:${arch_version}"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:${arch_version}"
```

These dependencies should have the same version. Either they are all 1.0.0 or 1.1.0. Different versions will cause problems.

Comment: Perfect answer.  For me it was the **android.arch.persistence.room:compiler** that was the wrong version.

Comment: Great. Thanks. You saved my time :)

Comment: Thanks, This is the perfect answer and problem is solved.

Comment: After changing android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.1.0-beta3 to android.arch.persistence.room:guava:1.0.0, the problem has been solved.